# CKEditor - Modify BB Code Plugin to generate Wiki Syntax?

Tags: syntax, ckeditor, wysiwyg, wiki, bbcode

I've been looking for a WYSIWYG editor that generates Wiki Syntax output for a long time, but haven't found anything so far. So, the closest I've found to what I'm looking for is CKEditor which has a plugin that converts the HTML output to BB Code.

Now I wonder, is there any (simple) way to modify this plugin so that it generates Wiki Syntax instead of BB Code? Or, maybe, has this been done by anyone already and I just don't find it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried CKEditor's Data Processor? (http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Data_Processor) like this :

```js
CKEDITOR.on('pluginsLoaded', function (event) {
  event.editor.dataProcessor.dataFilter.addRules({
      elements: {
        p: function (element) {
          // element.attributes
        }
      }
    });

  event.editor.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules({
      elements: {
        p: function (element) {
          // element.attributes ...
        }
      }
    });
});
```

I think your best choice would be [MindTouch deki wiki](http://www.mindtouch.com/)

[Foswiki](http://foswiki.org) is nice too, but for your use case (windows) will be harder to set up.

Also [MediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki) (the engine behind Wikipedia) may be a a good option. It is very poor feature-wise and has no WYSIWYG, but the Wikipedia reputation (and its simplicity) may make it a much less intimidating option than better engines for the non-techies. If your non-tech population view the arrival of a wiki as a burden (*"what are these geeks going to force us to use now?"*) this could be a good option, as however good the WYSIWYG-in-a-browser solutions are they aren't near the power and comfort of Word.

I think you can pimp [EpicEditor](http://epiceditor.com/) instead of CKEditor:

> EpicEditor is an embeddable JavaScript Markdown editor with split fullscreen editing, live previewing, automatic draft saving, offline support, and more. For developers, it offers a robust API, can be easily themed, and allows you to swap out the bundled Markdown parser with anything you throw at it.

Comment: Thanks, that seems useful! Still, it would be great if you could give me just one example of how to convert HTML to Wiki Syntax inside the addRules function, like how to turn <b>text</b> into ** text **.